# Python Webscraping real time

Tags: python, web-scraping

I wrote a program that scrapes from a downloaded html file. I would like it to actaully scrape websites on real time. Can someone please help me with what I need to change? I am not sure how to move this from a downloaded file to a real time website.

```
 def getStockValue(source):

        start = source.find("fac-yshl")
        start = source.find("data-value", start + 1)
        start = source.find('"', start + 1)
        value = source[start:source.find('"',start + 1)]

        value = value.replace('"',"")
        value = value.replace("'","")

        print "stock Value :",value
        return value
    # end of getStockValue()


def openFile(file):
# read a list, return a dic
        try: #is the file there??
                data = open(file, "r").read() #returns a string
                return data
        except IOError:
                print "  \aNo such file!!!! \"",file,"\" so exiting"
                sys.exit(1)
#end of openFile()


def begin(inFile):
#infile is the name of the html file that is saved from google's stock page
#starter file
    print "Loaded file,", inFile," Stockmarketprice:"
    source = open(inFile,"r").read() # load the whole file.
    source = openFile(inFile) # load the whole file.
    stockValue = getStockValue(source)

    print "  Loaded file,", inFile,"\n  Stock market price:",stockValue
# end of begin()


import sys

if __name__ == '__main__':
    if len(sys.argv) == 2:
         begin(sys.argv[1])
    else:
         sys.exit(0)
```

Comment: What do you mean "scrape in real time"?

Comment: I guess real time wasn't exaclty what I wanted to say. I do not want to have to download the html file of a website in order to webscrape.

Comment: Where's the part of your code where you actually scrape?

Comment: You always have to download the website... You could try to stream the website and scrap it part for part.

Answer (score 0):

Look into BeautifulSoup and requests, here is an example from one of my side projects that did what I think you want to do to:

```
first_page = requests.get("http://store.steampowered.com/search/?" + filter)
html = BeautifulSoup(first_page.content, "html.parser")
```

When you say download I'm assuming you mean manually doing it. This still "downloads" the html but it doesn't store it in memory and it does it for you.